# MongoDB aggregation pipeline $limit cast exception from string to int

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, bson

Trying to cast from `string` to `int` in aggregation is throwing the following error: `$limit should be a number not object or string`. Here is my query:

`{ $limit: { "$convert": { "input": "10", "to": "int" } } }`

OR

`{ $limit: { $toInt: "5" } }`

For More details:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) ,

The `$limit` stage has the following prototype form:

`{ $limit: <positive integer> }`

I think you can only use a positive integer. You need to make it integer instead of string.

Comment: Thank you for your time , Agree the documentation says it support only positive integer. The value will come from  from service  dynamically .  So Using typecasting(from string to INT)   as suggested by [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/). The problem here is the typecasting is not working

Comment: I think after $limit, expecting an integer, instead of an <expression> or <query>

Comment: Yes in Mongo  Pipe Linequery  $skip and $limit not accepting any expression and typecasting it is accepting  only integer. Fixed the problem by using string replace of pipeline query at server side .